# Can't get preg_match working for web scraping

Tags: php, html, regex, web-scraping

I have some code here, but I can't get it working. Could someone help me?

```
$file_string = file_get_contents('URL');
$search = "<tr><th> <a href=''>Data_name</a></th><td>(.*)</td></tr>";
preg_match($search, $file_string, $title);
$title_out = $title[1];
echo $title_out;
```

Comment: [Please don't use Regexp to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1607098) Take a look at [DOM](http://php.net/dom) instead

Comment: What isn't working, is there an error? You are missing an `";` at the end of line 2

Comment: If you must use Regex, please post examples of the data you're searching and some expected matches/non matches.

Comment: Can you show the html content of the page you trying to scrap data from ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what @Touki said - but this may help you with any future regex problems you might have:

1. You probably aren't looking at anything beyond the first line. You want to use "[multiline](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)"
2. `<tr><th> <a href=''>Data_name</a></th><td>(.*)</td></tr>` seems to look at pretty exact string. Ensure your white space is correct (tabs, spaces, new lines etc). You also seem to be missing a hyperlink, not sure if that was intentional or not.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that regular expressions in PHP require delimiters.